# Round a floating point number to n digits ignoring leading zeros and preserving them

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

Floating Point = 11.0000123456789

I want to round the above floating point number to 11.00001235. So I want the base portion of the float rounded to 4 digits while ignoring and preserving the leading zeros and adding back in the significand at the end.

I have the following, it is short and sweet but feels a little bit like a work around.

```
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = 4
significand, base = str(11.0000123456789).split('.')
fp = significand + str(decimal.Decimal('.' + base) + 0)[1:]  # I need to add 0 here for it to work
print(fp)
```

I can't really find an answer to my specific question. I want to know what the most pythonic way of achieving this is or if what I have is decent enough. It feels a little shoddy to me.

Edit: the number of leading zeros is unknown and I chose four for the example. So I don't think string formatting will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: for an unknown number of 0's I don't see a better alternative than

```
import re
some_float = 11.00001203456789
how_many_to_keep = 4
regex = r"0[1-9]"
float_part = str(some_float).split(".")[1]
float_limiter = re.search(regex,float_part).start() if float_part.startswith("0") else -1
print(f'{some_float:2.{float_limiter+1+how_many_to_keep}f}')
```

Which is evaluating the number of 0 in real time using the expression `float_limiter+1+how_many_to_keep`,  and use as a the format parameter. this has gotten a bit ugly but now returns the correct answer on all cases. The output is

> 11.00001235

Comment: I should have mentioned that that number of leading zeros is unknown. I just chose four leading zeros for the example so string formatting will not work.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of attention, the edit would serve your goal

Comment: thanks that does work @ rotem. I wish there something more pythonic haha but what I am doing is most likely not very common.

Comment: @rotemtal, when I assign `11.00001023456789` to the `some_float `, the output is `11.0000102346`. It display `6` characters after the last zero.

Comment: @KushanGunasekera correct, I've edited my code it should now return the correct value in these cases

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the most pythonic way to solve your problem. Try this,

```py
>>> import re
>>>
>>> float_val = 11.0000123456789
>>> keep_places = 4
>>>
>>> regEX = f'[0-9]+\.[0]+{"[0-9]" * keep_places}'
>>> expected_val = re.search(regEX, str(float_val)).group()
>>>
>>> print(expected_val)
'11.00001234'
```

The easiest way is create the [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) and this is how I use it to solve your question. Let's break it into 4 parts.

1. **`[0-9]+`**
2. **`\.`**
3. **`[0]+`**
4. **`[0-9] * keep_places`**

(1). `[0-9]` mean select only one digit in between 0 and 9. We need multiple digit before the decimal point. That's why we add `[0-9]+`. If you don't have any integers before the decimal point, then add `*` instead of `+`, it check zero or more occurrences. If you're using `+` mean you must have one or more values.

(2). `.` this dot is a special character to select any character except newline character from the given string. We need to capture decimal point which also a dot. If our string has these kind of special characters(in our case a decimal point) we use `\` to match those characters. That's why we use `\.`, it now can match our decimal point.

(3). `[0]+`, this will match all the zeros in our string.

(4). `[0-9] * keep_places`, this is just a string multiplication. For this question `keep_places` is `4` which mean we get this kind of output `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`. But in [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re), it select only four digit which each digit in between 0 and 9. One more thing, for this question it doesn't matter you're using `[0-9]` or `[1-9]`. Because we already capture zeros, it start to find other integers from `1`.

If you print `regEX`, all togeather you'll see `[0-9]+\.[0]+[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` kind of string. It matches `<any_number><dot><all_zeros_before_the__non_zero_integer><4_digit_after_last_zero>` type of pattern only. You can test this expression [online](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=110051).

Comment: I would like to use that but it will not work if the number of leading zeros directly after the decimal point change.

Comment: Did you try it @probat? just change `keep_points` to 4, you'll get `11.0000`.

Comment: No, I did not try it but I know what that does. That is not the behavior that I asked for. I wanted to keep all leading zeros directly after the decimal point but then round the non-zero numbers while keeping n digits where n can be any number. Also the number of leading zeros can be any amount of zeros. I simply chose four leading zeros just for this example. In this example I posted, I want the final float to be `11.00001235` but what you gave me will not work if the initial float has 9 leading zeros. I would have to always update the `keep_point` variable. It needs to work with all floats.

Comment: thanks @Kushan, I do appreciate you taking time to help.

Comment: You're welcome @probat, I updated my answer. Please check it and let me know. I hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

An issue with @Rotem's answer is that it won't account for all leading 0s (number between 0-1), this small edit fixes that.

```
def round_to_N_ignoring_leading_zeros(ending_values_to_keep, number):
"""
rounds the number off to N trailing decimals, ignoring leading values (including 0)
1.000016 -> 1.00001600
0.000016 -> 0.00001600
11.0000123456789 -> 11.00001235

:param ending_values_to_keep:
:param number:
:return:
"""
import re
altered = False
if number < 1:
    altered = True
    number += 1
regex = r"0[1-9]"
float_part = str(number).split(".")[1]
float_limiter = re.search(regex, float_part).start() if float_part.startswith("0") else -1
number -= 1
return eval(f'{number:2.{float_limiter + 1 + ending_values_to_keep}f}')
```